# Qtile does not start on my Arch linux (VM)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, tiling-wm

Hi guys I would like some guide with this problem that I just faced. JFYI I am beginner Arch user and I had in mind that in addition to learn how to install Arch linux, learn about how to install and setup my first tilling window manager as well. So, that said I followed all instructions and step from the documentation about how to use Qtile on Arch (I mean, I have already installed qtile package and create the config file
`config.py` under the following path `~/.config/qtile/`). Nevertheless, when I tried to run Qtile using: qtile start. I got some errors like these following:

[image]

I have already tried to investigate that error on Google, but there is no a specific solution for this (apparently) and most of the case there has been any solution for this one. So, I would like the support for any Arch linux guru user that can be willing to give a hand to this noobie Arch user. Thank in advance.

Please let me know if you need more information to debug correctly this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `startx /usr/bin/qtile start`. According to the [wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Qtile#Xorg), you need to run command with `xinit`.